# Windows Vpn Server & Client Solution (Like Kerio)

Tags: vpn

I need a VPN Server + Client Application like Kerio WinRoute anybody know any good solution?
( the problem i have with kerio is that it does not limit users to a single connection so many computers can connect to vpn server with a single username at the same time)

I don't like OpenVPN cause it's very difficult to setup!

Comment: openvpn is not very difficult. come on - invest 30 minutes, start with this http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

definitively [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) - it has windows version [ recently even gui ]. might have a bit steep learning curve but is worth it. openvpn will give you really plenty of flexibility...

regarding login - you will most probably need to use keys distributed to end-users.

Answer (score 3):

Try [OpenVpn](http://www.openvpn.net/)
It is a great solution for anyone needing a quick multi platform client and server VPN solution. the best part is its free. check it out and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is a great way to enable remote VPN access and it should work in Windows: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html. Be patient, it might be not as easy to set it up as kerio.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's ISA Server product contains a PPTP / L2TP VPN server. The client comes with any Windows release since XP.

You  could also try open source VPN solutions like OpenVPN or  FreeSwan.

You can also use SSH tunneling as a kind of poor man's VPN.

Comment: Where is the ISA client included? Are you sure?... I know that if you are on a AD network, you can set a group policy to automatically install it, but I am pretty sure it isn't there by default.

Comment: Run the "Connect to a network" wizard and select "work place, VPN".

Comment: @twaltari, The ISA client and the standard windows VPN are different.

Answer (score 0):

How about the builtin RRAS? It requires no third party software on the server or the client.